# Getting a Sum to print out from a user defined array summed recursively

Tags: java, recursion, sum

I'm trying to get my program to print out the sum of an array of elements that are user defined. I have most of it done, but I get an error at the end where I want to print out the sum. Here's the program I have and the error is from the sumArray.length in the main class' print line:

```java
import java.util.*;
/**
 * SumArray
 *
 * @author (Sean Hall)
 * @version (4/13/21)
 */
public class SumArray
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int sumArray = makeArray();
        System.out.println("Sum of numbers equals: " + findSum(sumArray, sumArray.length)); //.length here gives the error
    }
     
    public static int makeArray()
    {
        System.out.print("Enter the total number of integers you want to sum up: ");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = keyboard.nextInt();
        int sumArray[] = new int [size];
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers to add, one value at a time: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            sumArray[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
    }
    
    public static int findSum(int sumArray[], int i)
    {
        if(i > 1)
        {
            return sumArray[i];
        }
        else
        {
            return sumArray[i] + findSum(sumArray, i-1);
        }
    }
}
```

I think I got it mostly correct, but do correct me if I did anything else wrong, I'm taking a Java intro class and this is one of my assignment problems.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: The error is generated because if an array has n elements (n == length), then the last element you can access is at index n - 1. This is because arrays are indexed starting with 0 (element 1 is at index 0). Solved this probem, you need to check the rest of the logic of your program.

Comment: `sumArray` is an **integer** in your code snippet. It doesn't have `.length`. Your `makeArray` method does **not** return an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;
/**
 * SumArray
 *
 * @author (Sean Hall)
 * @version (4/13/21)
 */
public class SumArray
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] sumArray = makeArray();
        System.out.println("Sum of numbers equals: " + findSum(sumArray, sumArray.length-1)); //.length here gives the error
    }

    public static int[] makeArray()
    {
        System.out.print("Enter the total number of integers you want to sum up: ");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = keyboard.nextInt();
        int[] sumArray = new int[size];
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers to add, one value at a time: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            sumArray[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        return sumArray;
    }

    public static int findSum(int sumArray[], int i)
    {
        if(i < 1)
        {
            return sumArray[i];
        }
        else
        {
            return sumArray[i] + findSum(sumArray, i-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here you go. There are many errors in this code. You should really go back and learn the basics. The first thing is that the array needs to be defined with [] brackets. Next you need to run the for loop in your sum method lenght-1 times.

I would suggest to revise how to implement arrays and how to use return.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this.

```
int[] nums = {1,3,5,7,9}
System.out.println(findSum(nums,0));
```

Prints

```
25
```

- first continue the method until you're at the next to last element.
- then simply add up the numbers indexed by the
  current value of `i` as the call stack unwinds.

```
public static int findSum(int sumArray[], int i) {
    int sum = 0;
    if (i < sumArray.length-1) {
       sum = findSum(sumArray, i+1);
   }
   return sum + sumArray[i];
}
```

I prefer doing it this way since you always call the method with the index starting at `0`, regardless of the array size.